# can an std::promise be made from a non-POD object?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, promise

One of the things my app does is listen for and receive payloads from a socket. I never want to block. On each payload received, I want to create an object and pass it to a worker thread and forget about it until later which is how the prototype code works. But for the production code I want to reduce complexity (my app is large) by using the convenient async method. async takes a future made from a promise. For that to work I need to create a promise on my non-POD object represented below by the Xxx class. I don't see any way to do that (see error in my sample code below). Is it appropriate to use async here? If so, how can I construct a promise/future object that is more complex than int (all code examples I've see either use int or void):

```
#include <future>
class Xxx //non-POD object
{
  int i;
public:
  Xxx( int i ) : i( i ) {}
  int GetSquare() { return i * i; }
};

int factorial( std::future< Xxx > f )
{
  int res = 1;
  auto xxx = f.get();
  for( int i = xxx.GetSquare(); i > 1; i-- )
  {
    res *= i;
  }
  return res;
}

int _tmain( int argc, _TCHAR* argv[] )
{
  Xxx xxx( 2 ); // 2 represents one payload from the socket
  std::promise< Xxx > p; // error: no appropriate default constructor available
  std::future< Xxx > f = p.get_future();
  std::future< int > fu = std::async( factorial, std::move( f ) );
  p.set_value( xxx );
  fu.wait();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried giving `Xxx` a default ctor?

Comment: Why don't you just pass `xxx` to the async function? Do you really need the two-way `future` communication? That just means both threads are waiting for each other.

Comment: I see. Since I already have the payload data, there is no need to make a promise/future out of it. Just use the asnyc's _Fty&& _Fnarg, _ArgTypes&&... _Args constructor with my complex arguments.

Comment: Right. You use a `future ` to get the result back _out_ of `async` but you don't need to use one to pass anything in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Mike already answered, it's definitely a bug in the Visual C++ implementation of `std::promise`, what you're doing should work.

But I'm curious why you need to do it anyway. Maybe there's some other requirement that you've not shown to keep the example simple, but this would be the obvious way to write that code:

```
#include <future>

class Xxx //non-POD object
{
  int i;
public:
  Xxx( int i ) : i( i ) {}
  int GetSquare() { return i * i; }
};

int factorial( Xxx xxx )
{
  int res = 1;
  for( int i = xxx.GetSquare(); i > 1; i-- )
  {
    res *= i;
  }
  return res;
}

int main()
{
  Xxx xxx( 2 ); // 2 represents one payload from the socket
  std::future< int > fu = std::async( factorial, std::move( xxx ) );
  int fact = fu.get();
}
```

Comment: Is auto xxx = f.get(); still necessary since I would no longer be  passing in a future?

Comment: Oops, well spotted. I forgot to change that bit, it's fixed now.

Comment: This is indeed a bug. I've submitted a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2229765/bug-std-promise-t-requires-that-t-is-defaultconstructible). This bug is even listed as a todo item in the <future> file ("// TODO: _Associated_state ctor assumes _Ty is default constructible") so the developers are well aware of it already.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your implementation is defective. There should be no need for a default constructor (per the general library requirements of [utility.arg.requirements]), and GCC accepts your code (after changing the weird Microsoftish `_tmain` to a standard `main`).

I'd switch to a different compiler and operating system. That might not be an option for you, so maybe you could give the class a default constructor to keep it happy.

Comment: Yup, definitely a bug in the implementation. `promise<Xxx>` should create an uninitialized buffer and only construct an `Xxx` object when `set_value` is called. Another workaround would be to use `boost::promise` instead of the `std` one

Comment: I'm a C++ MFC-hugger from way back. I skipped the Java and C# technical digressions and am happy to use these new ISO paralellization capabilities along with all my other C++ libraries (GUI, encryption, etc.). Actually, according to Herb Sutter at 2014 Build, it was MS that submitted their async implementation to the standards community for inclusion. I assume [utility.arg.requirements] states that you should be able to pass any kind of arg in a promise?

Comment: [utility.arg.requirements] is not specific to `promise` it just says "In general, a default constructor is not required."